# Problem in finding general term $(T_n)$ of given series

Tags: summation

**Question:**

> What is the sum up to $n$ terms of the following series? $$3+8+22+72+266+1036\dots$$

**My Approach:**
$$S_n=3+8+22+72+266+1036\dots T_n$$
$$-S_n=0-3-8-22-72-266-1036\dots-T_n$$
$$T_n=3+5+14+50+194+770\dots ({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})$$
$$-T_n=0-3-5-14-50-194-770\dots-({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})$$
$$({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})=3+2+9+36+144+576\dots+({T_{n-1}}-{T_{n-2}})$$
$$({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})=5+9+36+144+576\dots+({T_{n-1}}-{T_{n-2}})$$
Now, this forms a $GP$ with $a=9$ and $r=4$.
$$\therefore ({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})=5+\sum^{n-2}_{r=1}9.4^{r-1}$$
$$\implies ({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})=5+3(4^{n-2}-1)$$
$$\implies ({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})=2+3.4^{n-2}$$
$${T_n}={T_{n-1}}+2+3.4^{n-2}$$
Now,
$$T_n=3+5+14+50+194+770\dots ({T_n}-{T_{n-1}})$$
$$\implies T_n=3+5+14+50+194+770\dots ({T_{n-1}}+2+3.4^{n-2}-{T_{n-1}})$$
$$T_n=3+5+14+50+194+770\dots 2+3.4^{n-2}$$

Which seems wrong to me, and I have no idea how to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: This is a [famous](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/find-the-sum-of-n-terms-of-the-series3822722661036/) question it seems

Comment: @e2-e4 I saw that, but I couldn't understand why $T_n=3+\sum{t_n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence:
$$3,8,22.72,266,1036,....$$
The first diferences are:
$$5, 14,50,194,760,.....$$
Second differences are in GP with common ratio 0f $4$:
$$ 9, 36, 144, 576,....$$
So the $k$ term is $T(k)=An+B+C4^k$
So we have $$T(1)=A+B+4C=3, T(2)=2A+B+16C=8, T(3)=3A+B+64C=22$$
Solving these eqns. we
Finally $$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} T(k)=2 \sum_{k=1}^n k+\sum_{k=1}^{n} 4^{k-1}=n(n+1)+\frac{4^n-1}{3
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_0=3,a_1=8,a_2= 22, \ldots$ etc.

So, you are looking for a term describing $\sum_{k=0}^na_k$.

The second differences of the members of the given sequence $(a_k)$ are $e_k=9\cdot 4^k$ ($k=0,1,2,\ldots$).

Hence, the first differences are
$$d_n = 5 +9\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^k=2+3\cdot 4^n$$

This gives

$$a_n = 3+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2+3\cdot 4^k)=2(n+1)+4^n$$

Finally, summing $a_k$ gives

$$s_n= \sum_{k=0}^na_k = \sum_{k=0}^n(2(k+1)+4^k)$$
$$=\boxed{(n+1)(n+2)+\frac 13(4^{n+1}-1)},\; n=0,1,2,\ldots$$